# How to display the values in another sheet in descending order using v look up

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Please help me to find a solution which am trying to sort out. my query is i want to display the values in another sheet using v lookup formula in descending order.

Comment: Your question, after your editing, is very ambiguous, and has no details.  Please see here on how to ask a good question.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I may have an answer that works for you.
Look at [Sheet1-GK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dVB7VzLACMhq9b62xMjU8QAE_ADsJFOZ-BMp2U2C88Y/edit#gid=921429127&range=C2) in your sample worksheet.
The formula I used is:

```
=vlookup(B2, filter('Price History'!A$2:B$18,'Price History'!A$2:A$18=B2),2,1)
```

Let me know if you need more.  I haven't tried to see if this can be made into an arrayformula, so it doesn't need to be copied down.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, let me check with this. will inform u... thanks again

Comment: the solution from you works perfectly, but i want to expand this equation  into another level. so may be i need your help once again. can u post your mail address or whatsapp number pls ?

Comment: @Dilju, I prefer to answer questions directly on this site, so that others can benefit as well, if our questions and answers are useful.  If you can explain what you are trying to do, showing your data and how you would like the result to look, I'll be hppy to try and help.